# Flutter: How to map a list of maps?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a very simple list of maps.

```dart
List<Map<String, String>> items = [
    { 'a': 'Some Text' },
    { 'b': 'Another Text' },
];
```

I want to map the above list to a dropdown list.

```
DropdownButton<String>(
  hint: Text('Select a value'),
  items: items.map((item) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: // how to get key here a, b
      child: // how to get value 'Some Text', 'Another Text'
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (String newValue) {
    setState(() {
      // ...
    });
  },
 ),
)
```

How to get the key of the map, item has a property `keys` but not `key` and `values` and not `value`.

Comment: ant reason for using `items.map`? why not `for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) DropdownMenuItem(...)` - here you can use `i` for a `value:`

Comment: @pskink I found it on the official dropdown documentation page but that was only for list of strings, I modified it a bit to include maps.

Comment: Why do you have a `List` of `Map`s instead of a single `Map`?  Do you need to support having duplicate keys?

Answer (score 2):

For this particular input:

```
    List<Map<String, String>> items = [
        { 'a': 'Some Text' },
        { 'b': 'Another Text' },
    ];
```

You can do a workaround by accessing all the keys/values using getters and locating its very first element like this.

```
      DropdownButton<String>(
          items: items.map((item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: item.keys.first,
              child: Text(item.values.first),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (value){},
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You need to use `DropdownButton<Map<String, String>>` 
You can adjust `Text("${value.keys.first} ${value.values.first}")` per your request 
code snippet

```
DropdownButton<Map<String, String>>(
          value: dropdownValue,
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
          iconSize: 24,
          elevation: 16,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
          underline: Container(
            height: 2,
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          ),
          onChanged: (Map<String, String> newValue) {
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = newValue;

              print(
                  "${dropdownValue.keys.first} ${dropdownValue.values.first}");
            });
          },
          items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<Map<String, String>>>(
              (Map<String, String> value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<Map<String, String>>(
              value: value,
              child: Text("${value.keys.first} ${value.values.first}"),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Map<String, String>> items = [
    {'a': 'Some Text'},
    {'b': 'Another Text'},
  ];

  Map<String, String> dropdownValue;

  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            DropdownButton<Map<String, String>>(
              value: dropdownValue,
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              iconSize: 24,
              elevation: 16,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
              underline: Container(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              ),
              onChanged: (Map<String, String> newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownValue = newValue;

                  print(
                      "${dropdownValue.keys.first} ${dropdownValue.values.first}");
                });
              },
              items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<Map<String, String>>>(
                  (Map<String, String> value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<Map<String, String>>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text("${value.keys.first} ${value.values.first}"),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```